# Seeking literature on public transit network connectivity metrics?

Tags: references, measurements, transportation, transit

Are you aware of any literature for measuring the connectivity of a public transit network, taking both route geometry and the schedule into account?

In other words, I'd like to design a process whereby one could feed in data about a transit network and its schedule, and the process would pop out some numbers that characterize the connectivity of the network - roughly, how convenient the connections are, how much time one has to wait to make a transfer from one route to another, or how likely it is that one can make a transfer from one route to another. Processes that require additional information, such as origin-destination demand or on-time performance, would be be interesting as well.

Such a process would be useful in quantifying the potential effects of a service change, in detecting and avoiding inadvertently breaking people's connectivity, and generally, in designing service to be optimally useful to passengers.

Comment: I was involved in a few transit LOS and forecasting exercises. Expand on the question perhaps with detailed examples or problems that you are trying to solve and I'll pitch in to help

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like a 'Level of Service' type analysis?

The Transportation Research Board have published a 'Transit capacity and quality of service manual' - containing a section specifically on 'Quality of Service', and the analysis of the various measures of quality of service. http://www.trb.org/Main/Public/Blurbs/153590.aspx

An example of how this has been implemented can be found in Florida. Florida Dept. of Transportation have been working on the development of a 'Transit level of service indicator' (TLOS) for public transport. http://www.dot.state.fl.us/transit/Pages/tlosfinalrpt.pdf

Comment: Note that TCQSM is getting updated soon.